# How to create uninstaller in visual studio setup project?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, installation, projects-and-solutions

I have created a visual studio setup project, but I don't know how to create uninstaller in my visual studio setup project, please tell me how to do that??

I am using Visual Studio 2005, Or is there any other software which creates complete setups with uninstaller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> > I have created a visual studio setup project, but I don't know how to create uninstaller in my visual studio setup project, please tell me how to do that??

Kazar's answer is correct.  The Visual Studio setup creates a .msi file that describes the installation in a database table.  .msi files are consumed by the Windows Installer engine msiexec.exe (much like .docx consumed by Word).  If the application is already installed, then the unistall/modify/repair options are presented.

> > I am using Visual Studio 2005, Or is there any other software which creates complete setups with uninstaller.

There are free and commercial products available.  There are two general types of installations for Windows:  Windows Installer (.msi) files and script-based installers.

Answer (score 3):

The msi file generated by visual studio setup projects is already both an installer and an uninstaller - run the msi setup file to install it, and then right-click on it to see the uninstall option.

Answer (score 2):

Your installed program will be shown in Control Panel > Add/Remove Programs. You will be able to just hit the "Remove" button there to uninstall your app.

MSI that VS has generated for you is a standard Microsoft installer package, that you can use to install/uninstall software. You can also run admin/silent installations etc, depending on custom command line parameters if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Quickest and easy solution can be found here:

http://tech.chitgoks.com/2009/02/06/visual-studio-create-an-uninstaller-shortcut-in-your-installer-wizard/

Answer (score 0):

if you know where the files were placed and what registry keys were set, you can delete and fix the registry,create an uninstaller program and bundle it with the program in question

the best way would to be to have a generic uninstaller program that takes config files